# CSS div disappears on scroll

Tags: css

I'm working on a site which uses pure CSS and hover states to build the drop-menu. The problem is that the number of navigation items are so many that the a user has to scroll to see it on smaller laptops. But what happens is the menu disappears before reaching the bottom as if a mouseout event has occurred. Is there a way to prevent this without having to convert the menu to javascript/jQuery?

http://spinov8.com/SNS_demo/shop

Comment: Post your code please.....HTML, CSS and scripts if any.

Answer (score 0):

Your dropdown seems to disappear with the rest of your navigation when you scroll down, as soon as you scroll upwards it reappears with your dropdown already open.

Comment: AHHHHH I see what it's doing. Thanks for noticing that. There is a moment it disappears before being fixed or something. This gives me a direction to look. Much appreciated.

Comment: I removed the jquery that was making it disappear on scroll down and reappear on scroll up so that it remains fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the jquery that was making it disappear on scroll down and reappear on scroll up so that it remains fixed.

Comment: Please, reply directly to the comment or edit your question , you should not add a answer for that. Thanks